# How to debug SWT layout?

Tags: java, debugging, layout, eclipse-plugin, swt

I see excess space in a view. How to find, what is it there? Is there any debugging option or tool for layout managing?

I have added `org.elipse.pde.picasso` plugin to my runtime config and set this plugin for tracing, but nothing happen visually.

I there something like `debug` style in `MigLayout`?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://kellicker.wordpress.com/2010/05/29/debugging-eclipse-ui-layouts-with-picasso/)? I also found [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/yari/). Finally, you can add `SWT.BORDER` to the style of a lot of components which will add (who would have thought) a border around them, so you can see how much space they occupy.

Comment: Also, there is [SWT Spy](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/tools.php).

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse PDE Layout spy is a very nice tool to identify layout issues. If you have PDE installed, press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F9 on any window to activate it.  See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlatformDevelopment/article.html#layout-spy for more information.

Comment: It would be nice to get an explanation on how to enable PDE spy in the runtime RCP.

Comment: @Sadık In RCP's run configuration, you can add the required plugin `org.eclipse.tools.layout.spy` and run your RCP. Then you can use the keyboard binding Crtl-Alt-Shift-F9 to open the Layout Spy Dialog and start debugging your layouts like vogella mentioned.

Comment: `org.eclipse.tools.layout.spy` doesn't show up (SWT Tools is installed). Only `org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.spy`. But with that, the mentioned keyboard shortcut doesn't do anything.

Comment: I think it is part of PDE and should already be around in an Eclipse for RCP and RAP. Please check your target platform content if you disabled there any plugins. When it is not disabled in the content either install it in the target platform or get it into your Eclipse by either Help / Install New Software or Help / Marketplace.